# web interface for R prediction model using Shiny

Tags: r, prediction, shiny-server

Hi I have a predictive model in R and I need the customers to input their data in a web interface so the classifier can predict the classes. I am using Shiny package but there is no output.

The first step is to let the customer input his data in a csv format. then the model is used in the back end to predict the classes of the input file. and then provides the customer in the web interface with the classes for each row.

```
    ########## Server
    bw <- read.csv("bw.csv", header = T)

    colnames(bw)[1] <- "class"

bw$class[bw$class=="1"] <- "A" 
bw$class[bw$class=="2"] <- "B" 
bw$class[bw$class=="3"] <- "C" 
bw$class[bw$class=="4"] <- "D" 
bw$class[bw$class=="5"] <- "E"

bw$class <- as.factor(bw$class) 
bw[ , 2:59]<- sapply(bw[ , 2:59], as.numeric)

control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=5, repeats=2)
# train the LDA model set.seed(7) 
modelLda <- train(class~., data=bw, method="lda", trControl=control)



library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {   output$contents <- renderTable({

    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
    # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
    # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
    # be found.

    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    head(read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep, 
             quote=input$quote))    })
     # classification
     clusters <- reactive({
    predict(modelLda, input$file1(), input$clusters)   })
     # Show clusters:   

    output$table1 <- renderTable({
        input$clusters   })

    })

########### UI
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                accept=c('text/csv', 
                         'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                         '.csv')),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
      radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                   c(Comma=',',
                     Semicolon=';',
                     Tab='\t'),
                   ','),
      radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                   c(None='',
                     'Double Quote'='"',
                     'Single Quote'="'"),
                   '"')
    ),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput("table1")
    )
  )
))
```

One final question, should the classifier model be included in the server.r file or can be called from another file?

Thanks.

Comment: you are using output$contents but then you use tableOutput("table1"). Try tableOutput("contents")

Comment: contents will show only the uploaded table. i need the predicted classes

Comment: you should print your cluster at the end of your output$contents statement and then call in your output$table1 <- renderTable({ input$contents}). the statement output$table1 should be outside the output$contents statement.

Comment: Sorry i am little bit new to this can you please be more detailed. Thanks.

Comment: I think there is no output because your output$table1 statement is inside the output$contents statement. Your should use the first statement to output the results of your model and then use the second statement to output as a table. Having a reproducible example (some data) would help.

Comment: please find the links to the following :- 1) whole data  https://www.dropbox.com/s/9csysjdxvbu3794/bw.csv?dl=0                       2) testdata                      https://www.dropbox.com/s/cxhr6g7e1kege18/bw_test.csv?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

here is something to help you started with (it worked for me). I simplified it but you will have an idea on how to structure it. hope it helps!

```
library(shiny)
library(caret)

    bw <- read.csv("bw_test.csv", header = T)

    colnames(bw)[1] <- "class"

bw$class[bw$class=="1"] <- "A" 
bw$class[bw$class=="2"] <- "B" 
bw$class[bw$class=="3"] <- "C" 
bw$class[bw$class=="4"] <- "D" 
bw$class[bw$class=="5"] <- "E"

bw$class <- as.factor(bw$class) 
bw[ , 2:58]<- sapply(bw[ , 2:58], as.numeric)

control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=5, repeats=2)
# train the LDA model set.seed(7) 
modelLda <- train(class~., data=bw, method="lda", trControl=control)



shinyServer(function(input, output) {  

    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
    # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
    # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
    # be found.

 #   inFile <- input$file1

  #  if (is.null(inFile))
   #   return(NULL)

    #head(read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep, 
     #        quote=input$quote))    })
     # classification


          dInput = reactive({

    in.file = input$file1

    if (is.null(in.file))
      return(NULL)

read.csv(in.file$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep, quote=input$quote)

  })


     clusters <- reactive({

        df <- dInput()

    tt <- as.data.frame(predict(modelLda))
    tt
    })
     # Show clusters:   



        output$table1 <- renderTable({
            toprint = clusters()
            head(toprint)
            })

        })
```

EDIT: now it will wait to download the file before printing the table, but now you are on your own :)

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {  

    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
    # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
    # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
    # be found.

 #   inFile <- input$file1

  #  if (is.null(inFile))
   #   return(NULL)

    #head(read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep, 
     #        quote=input$quote))    })
     # classification


          dInput = reactive({

    in.file = input$file1

    if (is.null(in.file))
      return(NULL)

 bw <- read.csv(in.file$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep, quote=input$quote)

     colnames(bw)[1] <- "class"

bw$class[bw$class=="1"] <- "A" 
bw$class[bw$class=="2"] <- "B" 
bw$class[bw$class=="3"] <- "C" 
bw$class[bw$class=="4"] <- "D" 
bw$class[bw$class=="5"] <- "E"

bw$class <- as.factor(bw$class) 
bw[ , 2:58]<- sapply(bw[ , 2:58], as.numeric)
bw

  })


     clusters <- reactive({

        df <- dInput()

            if (is.null(df))
      return(NULL)
        control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=5, repeats=2)
        modelLda <- train(class~., data=df, method="lda", trControl=control)

    tt <- as.data.frame(predict(modelLda))
    tt
    })
     # Show clusters:   



        output$table1 <- renderTable({
            toprint = clusters()
            head(toprint)
            })

        })
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply, but the predicted classes pops up before inputing the new test set. I cant figure out the reason.

Comment: you will have to change a few things but I just wanted to restructure your various statements in your previous Server. I am not that all familiar with Caret but I expect, you will need to change something in here  tt <- as.data.frame(predict(modelLda, input$dInput())).

Comment: the following error pops up    error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.data.frame': Error in predict.train(modelLda, input$dInput()) : 
  attempt to apply non-function

Comment: you can accept the answer if this is what you wanted :)